# how does FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED property works?

Tags: response, mediator, wso2-esb

my proxy code looks like this

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test">
 <target>
   <inSequence><property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/></inSequence>
 </target>
</proxy>
```

when I hit xml from soapUI I'm not expecting response.
From my understanding FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED property forces a 202 http response to the client so it stops waiting for a response when this property is set to true. 
please can anybody suggest how FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED property works?

Comment: FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED works exactly as you said : what is your question ?

Comment: yeah, but how can I test ? I'm unable to receive any response after hitting input from soapUI.

Comment: I've deployed your proxy in my ESB 4.8.1 and have call it with SoapUI : in Raw tab, I can see HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 10:15:18 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive
Nothing else to expect...

Comment: what is mean of Raw tab ? isn't it response tab in soapUI ? I'm new to wso2esb could you tell me where does it present?

Comment: It has nothing to do with WSO2 ESB : in SoapUI, in response tab, you can see the "content" but in your case, there is no data, just http headers with http status code set to 202 and you can see these informations into raw tab

Answer (score 1):

This parameter is only applied when you use the  or  mediator in your sequence.
In that case the calling client will receive a 202 immediately without waiting for the response.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test"><target>
   <inSequence>
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
        
        <!-- 202 response will directly be sent to caller -->
        <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8280/anyapi">
                    </address>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <!-- managing the response from the call, but <respond/> mediator cannot be used anymore, as already responded -->
         
    </inSequence></target></proxy>
```

So in your example without "call" or "send" mediator, you'll get a 200. You can change that by setting the HTTP_SC yourself (and removing the body):

```
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="202" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" value="true" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN"/>
<respond/>
```